# Downloaded page source in R is different than rendered page source in Chrome

Tags: r, url, web-scraping

I am trying to use R to pull URL's from a google search with specific dates. The URL is [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=broncos&biw=1920&bih=950&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F01%2F2017%2Ccd_max%3A01%2F31%2F2017&tbm=nws), is a google news search from Jan 1st 2017-Jan 31st 2017. Viewing the page source when navigating to the link is  different than when I run:

```
  url<-"https://www.google.com/search?q=broncos&biw=1920&bih=950&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F01%2F2017%2Ccd_max%3A01%2F31%2F2017&tbm=nws"
  dat <- GET(url)
  page <- htmlParse(dat,asText = T)
  capture.output(dat, file="file.html")
  htmltxt <- paste(capture.output(page, file=NULL), collapse="\n")
```

Any ideas on how I could go about getting the page source for my specific url in R?

Comment: "Any ideas?" isn't a very specific question. Websites can serve different pages based on how is asking or how they ask. Most modern webpages rely on executing javascript to deliver content and R does not natively run javascript. Maybe look into something like Rselenium if you need to pass requests through a web brower.

Comment: Rselenium is my way to go as well - it saves the current page and therefore is exactly what are you looking for.